# WordPress - Disable new user email confirmation/validation ( Single Install )

Tags: wordpress, email-validation

**I don't want new users to have to confirm their account via email when registering on WordPress!** Simple.

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now to tweak this rather simplistic issue. Email confirmation is important but can cause lots of issues when you have dumb/non-savvy users. *The whole world* seems to have a solution for this when it comes to WPMU, but I can't find anything for just plain single WordPress.

This is for a voting type site where we just want a person's details on a WP user account and then get them to just start voting seconds later.

Comment: Heeling the same frustration now.